# Asp.net core blazor web assembly example project not working

Tags: asp.net-core, webassembly, blazor-client-side

I dint add any code, its just the example project After creating the Blazor Web Assembly project on visual studio 2019 preview. 
[image]

Answer (score 0):

I fixed this by selecting .net core 3.1 framework which previously I had selected .net core 3.0. I added the template for .net core 3.1 in command prompt using the following command:

```
dotnet new -i Microsoft.AspNetCore.Blazor.Templates::3.1.0-preview4.19579.2
```